# Qt adding a derived QListwidgetitem to QListWidget

Tags: c++, qt

I have subclassed QTreeWidget, QTreeWidgetItem and QListWidgetItem. I am trying to add my custom QListWidgetItem to QListWidget but its not getting displayed in the view.

I Have created a dialog. I have inserted a QTreeWidget and QListWidget.
What I want is when I click a Item in QTreeWidget, The QListWidget should get populated with the my custom QListWidgetItems i.e. CustomListWidgetItems contained in the clicked CustomTreeWidgetItem (QTreeWidgetItem derived class).
If I use QListWidgetItem instead of CustomListWidgetItems, every thing works fine.

Header file contents:

```
class CustomTreeWidgetItem : public QTreeWidgetItem
{
public:
    explicit CustomTreeWidgetItem(int type = Type);
public:
    QList<CustomListWidgetItem*> projects;//Items to populate ListWidget
};

class CustomListWidgetItem : public QListWidgetItem
{
public:
    explicit CustomListWidgetItem(const QIcon & icon, const QString & text, QListWidget * parent = 0, int type = Type);
    CustomListWidgetItem(const int& id,QString Name,QString Description,QString icon);

public:
    int Id;
    QString Name;
    QString Description;
    QString Icon;
};
```

Source contents of Custom Listwidgetitem:

```
CustomListWidgetItem::CustomListWidgetItem(const QIcon &icon, const QString &text, QListWidget *parent, int type) : QListWidgetItem(icon,text,parent,type)
{

}

CustomListWidgetItem::CustomListWidgetItem(const int& id,QString Name,QString Description,QString icon)
{
    this->Id = id;
    this->Name = Name;
    this->Description = Description;
    this->Icon = icon;

    QString iconPath = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/" + icon + ".png";
    QIcon qIcon(iconPath);
    QListWidgetItem::QListWidgetItem(qIcon,Name);
}
```

Source contents:

```
void CustomTreeWidget::treeitemSelected(QTreeWidgetItem * item, int)//Tree item click event
{
    CustomTreeWidgetItem *project = static_cast<CustomTreeWidgetItem*>(item);

        if(LISTWIDGET)
        {
            m_listWidget->clear();
            m_listWidget->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);

            int count = project->projects.count();

            if(count == 0)
            {
                m_listWidget->addItem("No Projects Here");//This gets displayed
                m_listWidget->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::NoSelection);
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
                {
                    m_listWidget->addItem(project->projects[i]);//This does not get displayed
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

During Debugging I can see that the data i.e Name, Description, etc. is present in "project->projects[i]". No error is shown during addItem function call still the items are not visible in view.

Answer (score 0):

Few questions:
 - Why do I have the feeling you mix listwidgetitem and treewidgetitem?
 - Why do you fill your view everytime an item is selected? is it initialized?
 - Can you show where you create the view and start adding items?

Check you have the following:

1. create a qtreewidget that you add to your view layout
2. add a root node using something like

   ```
   QTreeWidgetItem *treeItemRoot = new QTreeWidgetItem(myTreeWidget);
   treeItemRoot->setText(0, projectName);
   ```
3. add children nodes

   ```
   QTreeWidgetItem *treeItemChild = new QTreeWidgetItem();
   treeItemRoot->addChild(treeItem);
   ```

and post the results.

Comment: I am not having any issues with QTreeWidgetItem. I want to populate a ListWidget with my custom QListWidgetItem derived class. If I use QListWidgetItem instead of derived, everything works fine. But I am not able to use Custom class. I have updated the question

Comment: The coupling between CustomListWidgetItem and CustomTreeWidgetItem  is weird. Is there anything in the CustomTreeWidgetItem::projects variable (not empty)? I would try to override the ::Data() method in the listwidgetitem in your case but it might be better to create a model object that is used by both the tree and the list...

Comment: projects variable contains a list of CustomListWidgetItems. Each TreeWidgetItem has its own list of CustomListWidgetItems which should get inserted in the listwidget on click event